# Close, maximize and minimize buttons disappear in winforms application under RDP on windows 8/2012 with no visual styles enabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rdp, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm looking for help with winforms application.

Our WinForms app is build under visual studio 2010 for .NET 4.0. We disabled all visual styles for it to look identically to another app (native) that was used along with ours. Users work under RDP on Windows Server 2008 R2. Everything was fine. 
Now we tested our app under Windows Server 2012 R2, but found that all forms have no close, minimize and maximize buttons drawn, but they are clickable and work as should.
Some research showed that it is due to disabling visual styles. I created a default empty windows forms application and reproduced the bug. I even tried visual studio 2013 and .NET 4.5.2, but it didn't help.

Simply create an empty windows forms application and change Main with:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.VisualStyleState = VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled;
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

You should run it under rdp on windows server 2012 r2 / 8 and [you'll see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztWav.png).

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with .NET or Winforms, that window chrome is painted by the operating system.  A wild guess is that RDP is configured to not transfer bitmaps.  Ask server and rdp questions at serverfault.com

Comment: You are right. I created a clean install of Windows Server 2012 R2 with no changes. It worked. All buttons were present.